# GeoServer complex WTMS/TMS/GWC trouble: No such operation gwc null service

Tags: geoserver, java, geowebcache, wmts, tile-map-service

I trying to solve a issue from replaced data dir on GeoServer. When I choose a WMTS / TMS services in GeoServer's 2.16 GUI I see this:
[image]
and 400:null too for TMS: `<ows:ExceptionText>No such operation gwc null service</ows:ExceptionText>`

In the log an error begins from this:

```
ERROR [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - Request failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.StyleParameterFilter.setLayer(StyleParameterFilter.java:188)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.TileLayerInfoUtil.checkAutomaticStyles(TileLayerInfoUtil.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.TileLayerInfoUtil.checkAutomaticStyles(TileLayerInfoUtil.java:140)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.getPublishedInfo(GeoServerTileLayer.java:358)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerTileLayer.isEnabled(GeoServerTileLayer.java:280) 
...
```

I tried to catch broken layers or styles after Tomcat's restart, but all looks ok, except this rows:

```
2019-10-01 12:27:16,107 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageFinder] - *** Reverting to java.io.tmpdir null for storage. Please set GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR. ***
2019-10-01 12:27:15,963 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** GWC configuration validation error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'gwcConfiguration'.
2019-10-01 12:27:15,963 WARN [config.XMLConfiguration] - *** Will try to use configuration anyway. Please check the order of declared elements against the schema.
```

How can I fix it all and make wmts/tms gwc work? I have to do something with unobtained style/layer or something more using 2 last WARNs ?

Comment: If I have to do all tomcat restarted log please comment about this. All log after error with wmts here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/333433/revisions

Answer (score 1):

It was a couple of problem: 
1)deleted styles for N layers.
2) using by N layers geogrid, wich doesn't exist.

Good way is find a aproach wich allows to detecte layers with broken styles.. What I did? I check it manually..

How to find layers with bad geogrid? You have to find this grid and next using something like that on your server in geoserver/data directory: `grep -Rl "name_of_geogrid"`